# Compute the optimal point $x^*$ and $f^* = f(x^*)$?

Tags: convex-optimization, gaussian-elimination

$$f(x) = max_i\{a_i^T x + b \}$$

with

$a_1 =\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$, $a_2=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\\ 
\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{pmatrix}$, $a_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\\ 
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{pmatrix}$, $b=-3$

I would use the Gaussian elimination and solve a system of 3 equations.

$$ \begin{matrix}
a_1^T \cdot [x_1, x_2]^T & = & -3 \\ 
a_2^T \cdot [x_1, x_2]^T & = & -3 \\
a_3^T \cdot [x_1, x_2]^T & = & -3 \\
\end{matrix}$$

... and got as result: $x^*= [-3, \frac{-3\sqrt(5)-3}{2}]^T$

I am not sure, shouldn't be the optimal point at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, I do not get f(x*) = x*

Comment: $x^*$ is not in $\Re^2$ because $f(x)$ is "almost" linear.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: A good formulation should be  $(\min\vert \max)_x f(x)$ with $f(x)=(\max\vert\min)_i\{a_i^{\top}x+b\}$

Comment: I do not understand you, because $min\{a_i^Tx+b\}$ returns only a scalar. $max$ would be redundant.

Comment: I posted my ideas as a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$
f(x) = \max_i\{a_i^{\top}x+b\}
$$

[image]

$$
f(x) = \min_i\{a_i^{\top}x+b\}
$$

[image]